# Misreading a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to have a loop read a multidimensional array defined in a separate class to place objects at the start of a game.

This is the Start function code from the LevelStart class:

```
void Start () {
    //Get Level
    Levels levels = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Levels>();
    level = levels.GetLevel (levelName);
    x = level.GetLength(1);
    y = level.GetLength (2);

    temp = GameObject.Find ("temp").GetComponent<Temp>();
    lPos = temp.GetLevelNum() - 1;   //Chosen Level

    //Read array and place objects
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            if (level[lPos,i,j] == 1) {
                Debug.Log ("Spawn Point");
            }
            else if (level[lPos,i,j] == 2) {
                Debug.Log ("Hole");
            }
            else if (level[lPos,i,j] == 3) {
                Debug.Log ("Obstacle");
            }
            else 
                Debug.Log ("Open Space");
        }
    }
}
```

And the class holding the arrays is Levels.cs:

```
public int[,,] cave = new int[,,] {
    {   //Level 1
        { 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
        { 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0},
        { 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0}
    },

    {   //Level 2
        { 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0 }
    }
};
```

It reads most of the array correctly but positions such as [0,0,0] and [0,0,12] returns 3's when it should be 0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me to be pretty likely that you're simply using the wrong level number - code that is not shown.  I suggest using the print statement to ensure temp.GetLevelNum() and lPos are the numbers you think they should be.

Comment: I did test for the level number with a Debug.Log statement right after temp.GetLevelNum() and it was correct.

Comment: And I'm meant to take your word for it?  What are they?  Take a look at http://www.sscce.org/ and reformat your question.